# Change Windows 7 Edition after install

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking to downgrade the version of windows 7 I have installed on my machine from Ultimate to Professional. I installed from and ISO I got off the MSDN but have just found out that I'm supposed to be using a retail licence on my machine. We've only got retail licences for Professional and I don't want to use and up the MSDN Licenses we have.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the answer you accepted is not true. Could you please change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way. See [Downgrade: Change Windows 7 Ultimate to Premium or Professional](http://www.unawave.de/installation/downgrade-en.html?lang=EN). I successfully downgraded from an unregistered Ultimate to a registered Professional edition using a [universal installation DVD](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/85813-windows-7-universal-installation-disc-create.html). You edit two registry keys to match the edition you want, then use the DVD to "upgrade", without booting from the DVD.

Here are the two keys to modify:

- `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EditionID`: change from `Ultimate` to `Professional` or `HOMEPREMIUM`
- `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName`: change from `Windows 7 Ultimate` to `Windows 7 Professional` or `Windows 7 HOMEPREMIUM`

Answer (score 0):

No, I guess you can't do that. The installed OS is not the same, it's not just about the key. (Maybe you could use the `Upgrade` point at install with a Professional disk.)

Comment: Not true. See my answer.

Comment: Someone keeps deleting my answer because it does not duplicate the linked content. I can't believe someone thinks it's better to have no answer than an answer that references instructions. :-/

Comment: @JimL - I saw yours after logging in, and it's the right answer. Will flag Q for moderator. (Not sure if they can switch which is the accepted answer.)

Comment: @JimL No problem, gotta make sure the truth is out there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply no, you can't (: You must reinstall your OS, to use another Edition.

NB! Microsoft offers to MS Windows 7 Ultimate and MS Windows 7 Professional owners, free downgrade to Windows Vista Ultimate / Business. You can find more about it on Microsoft TechNet if you want.

Comment: Not true. See my answer.